# Apache SSL for login and NON-SSL for everything else (.htacces)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I've almost figured it out on my own but there's something I'm missing.
I want to set a couple of directories and files to require SSL and everything else that's not related to those files and dirs to point back to http.

So far I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Force ssl for login & admin
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^/?(admin(.*)|login\.php)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,NC,L]

# Force non-ssl for others 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?(admin(.*)|login\.php)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I just can't figure it out.... 
The first condition works perfect - whenever I access login.php or /admin/ it points to https. But the second one doesn't...

Where have I mistaken ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely to:

```
RewriteRule !^/?(admin(.*)|login\.php)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

My working config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^admin$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^admin$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Test:

```
http://localhost/admin->https://localhost/admin
https://localhost/admin don't redirect
https://localhost/test->http://localhost/test
```

Tesing:

```
# wget --no-check-certificate https://localhost/dgfjt943jreiorgd
--2011-01-31 16:55:18--  https://localhost/dgfjt943jreiorgd
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
WARNING: certificate common name `xxx.com' doesn't match requested host name `localhost'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://localhost/ [following]
--2011-01-31 16:55:18--  http://localhost/
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Comment: The code seems perfectly logic but it's not working ?

Comment: I test it(Ubuntu 10.04,Apache2,wget) and it's working.

Comment: Slackware 13.1x64 with apache 2.2.17 and when you accessing http://localhost/admin -> https://localhost/admin , but when you access https://localhost/somethingjusttobesure.html you stay on HTTPS ?

Comment: I add wget test... You can write me a mail

Comment: I've got no idea how I manage to get it working ... But your code really works... I knew it was something I was doing not right. Thank you for your help and effort to solve my problem! :)